# Do any Japanese words start with n besides ンジャメナ?

Tags: words, readings, katakana

Do any Japanese words start with n besides ンジャメナ or words related to it? 
 N'Djamena is the capital of Chad.

Comment: The premise of the game [しりとり](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiritori) is based on the idea that no native Japanese words start with ん.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you'd count as a "Japanese word". Almost certainly nothing that is natively Japanese will start with ん. However, there are a few words in other languages that would have it. For example, "ng" is a common starting sound in names in a few languages (including Vietnamese and some Chinese dialects). I know of someone whose surname is "Ng", and it caused a lot of trouble in getting them registered in some Japanese systems since there was an automatic validation preventing them from writing it as ング.

Comment: The famous [Andrew Ng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng), for example...

Comment: Not the one I'm talking about, but definitely a good example.